# Remove elements from vector of user defined data type in C++

Tags: c++

I have a structure of the form given below:

```
 struct A{
     int t; int j;}
```

The objects of struct A contains the following values:

```
     t      j
     20     191
     111    18
     888    90
```

I have kept all these objects in std::vector. Now I want to delete the elements from this vector where t==111 and j<20. Now I am iterating over the vector in order to remove the elements in the manner given below:

```
std::vector<A>::size_type i = 0;
while ( i < v.size() ) {
    if ( (v[i].t==111) && (v[i].j<20) ) {
        v.erase( v.begin() + i );
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Instead of iterating is there a better way to delete the elements in std::vector of user defined data types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
#include <algorithm>

v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                       [](A const & x) { return x.t == 111 && x.j < 20; }),
        v.end());
```

Comment: Can you please explain as to what does "[](A const & x)" imply in the function erase.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) with [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const A& a) {
  return a.t == 111 && a.j < 20;
}), v.end());
```

This basically moves all of the elements for which the lambda returns `true` to the back of the vector and then erases them all in one go.

Comment: Can you please explain as to what does "[](A const & x)" imply in the function erase.

Comment: @user1778824 The `[](const A& a) { ... }` is a lambda expression. You need a C++11 compiler for it to work.

Comment: I am using gcc as compiler...would it work for me...if not then please suggest an alternative